# Use ObjectiveC from Swift in framework, without making ObjC code public

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have framework that is written in ObjC and Swift, I want to use ObjC classes in Swift. Apple says ["In your umbrella header file, import every Objective-C header you want to expose to Swift"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). But everything included to umbrella becomes public. Is there any way to use ObjC without making it public?

Answer (score 0):

The umbrella header is not your framework header, it's the one named with "-Swift.h" in it.  You don't need to include that header in your main framework header.

Comment: I think apple speaks here not about "-Swift.h" as it it generated automatically, but they speak about framework header https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html

Comment: I would just try it -- import your ObjC in the -Swift. Do not include in the framework header and then check that your framework works.